# Unwanted padding on link images in IE only

Tags: image, internet-explorer, hyperlink, padding

I hope someone can help. Within my container DIV I have 3 images which I require to sit side by side in one row. This is indeed the case in every other browser except, annoyingly, as usual, in IE6, IE7 and IE8 (groan).

Each of the images is wrapped in an  tag as follows:-

```
<div id="images">

<a href="images/image01.jpg" rel="milkbox[group]" title="my image details01"><img src="images/image01b.jpg" width="98" height="92" alt="my image details01" class="img01"></a>

<a href="images/image02.jpg" rel="milkbox[group]" title="my image details02"><img src="images/image02b.jpg" width="98" height="92" alt="my image details02" class="img02"></a>

<a href="images/image03.jpg" rel="milkbox[group]" title="my image details03"><img src="images/image03b.jpg" width="99" height="92" alt="my image details03" class="img03"></a>
```

```
</div><!--end of images-->
```

My CSS is as follows:-

```
    /* Global reset */
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     outline: 0;
     font-weight: inherit;
     font-style: inherit;
     font-size: 100%;
     font-family: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    a img, :link img, :visited img {
     border: 0;
     display:block;
     }

    img{
    display:block;
    }
    /* End Global reset */

#images{
width:295px;
clear:both;
border:none;
margin-top:30px;
}

#images a:link{
text-decoration:none;
border:none;

}
#images a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
border:none;    
}
#images a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
border:none;

}

img.img01,img.img02 {
width:98px;
float:left;

}

img.img03{
width:99px;
float:right;

}
```

No matter what I do I can't seem to correct the display in IE. IE is adding additional padding to the left and right of each image, and the result is that 2 images only display within the row and the the 3rd image appears below it (floated right).

I have tried removing all white space (a suggestion i came across elsewhere) but that hasn't helped. I've also played around with negative margins but I'd prefer not to go down that route without understanding what's actually occurring.

Can anyone please shed some light on what's actually going on here and how I can resolve ? - it's drving me nuts !

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put up a test page on jsbin.com  
Then we can all see what the result of the above css is

Answer (score 2):

There is a whitespace issue with IE...try removing the spacing between your  tags and put them on a single line.

```
<div id="images"><a href="images/image01.jpg" rel="milkbox[group]" title="my image details01"><img src="images/image01b.jpg" width="98" height="92" alt="my image details01" class="img01"></a><a href="images/image02.jpg" rel="milkbox[group]" title="my image details02"><img src="images/image02b.jpg" width="98" height="92" alt="my image details02" class="img02"></a><a href="images/image03.jpg" rel="milkbox[group]" title="my image details03"><img src="images/image03b.jpg" width="99" height="92" alt="my image details03" class="img03"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at how IE calculates width. The 3 images have a total width of 295 and your div has a total width of 295. That 295 width of the div is measured from the outside of the div and unfortunately the content area of the div is less than 295. As an experiment increase the width of the div and see if the images display properly.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) is one page that describes it. Just search for IE Box Model in google.